# Rendering only working when scrolling or moving mouse

Tags: three.js

I have a big problem getting my animation to work, nothing animates in the scene unless I look around with my mouse. And as soon I stop looking around the animation stops. Tried alot of things and can´t figure it out what im doing wrong.

```
function onMouseMove(e) {
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
}    

window.addEventListener( "mousemove", onMouseMove, false );
window.requestAnimationFrame(render);


function animate(){
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function render(){

    sunArray[1].rotation.y += 0.01;
renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it call requestAnimation frame repeatedly:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

should work

Comment: I already have that, and if you mean inside the animate function it just makes whole browser freeze.

Comment: Well in the code snippet you posted you *don't* have that. If you still have issues, try making it a jsfiddle

Answer (score -2):

```
function animate(){
 sunArray[1].rotation.y += 0.01;
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function render(){
renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```

Comment: By doing this you have two renderer calls now, which is unnecessary. What you just want to add to your ```animate``` function is ```sunArray[1].rotation.y += 0.01;``` instead of ```render();```

Comment: Changed that, thanks did not know that. Changed to your solution.